Customize Wordpress Password-Reset Behavior
quite a lot of my users dont receive the Password Reset Mails. It seems they are flagged as spam by some providers, probably due to an HTML Link (automatically converted by Brevo/Sendinblue) in combination with Password Key. All my MX records are correct, I'm using Sendinblue SMTP service, ALL other mails go through. So it seems it has something to do with the Password-reset link.
Right now, when using Password-reset, users receive a mail wth a link like that:
example.net/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=somekeyhere&login=usernamehere
I would like to change the behavior so that after entering the mail address, Wordpress sends a mail ONLY with the authentication code (key somekeyhere) without a link - and the user is directy presented a input form entry where he/her shall enter the auth-key to be actually redirected to that final url above.
Goal is that the mail being sent only contains the key, not a full URL w.r.t. password reset, to avoid any Spam filters to trigger.
Has anyone yet done this? I don't want to modify the core but there are very few hooks available. Yes, I can customize the message of the mail sent (Hook retrieve_password_message). But I cannot really customize the process to show yet another input field after submitting your account mail. Because this is burried in wp-login.php (case 'checkemail') without a real hook present to modify that behavior.
Any ideas?!
